# Add button to the wish list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

I am developing an e-commerce site with java-ee, and I am stuck on the add to wish list button.

Here is an explanatory image:

[image: picture 1]

the blue button that is in each card is the button in i speak.

In fact I want that as soon as I click on this button the chosen product is added to the wish list and that this icon:

[image: picture 2]

increment by 1 example here there is the number 3 at the top of the icon, I want that as soon as I click on the button, the chosen product is added to the wish list and the number that is in the icon increases, for example in this example it will be 4.

The problem is that I really don't know how to do it, I know when can do this thanks to js but I have no idea what the code looks like to increase the number that is in the icon.

If anyone would give me sites that explain this or explain to me how to do it I would be very grateful to them.

Comment: *"I really don't know how to do it"* isn't a question, please see [ask].

Comment: Hi- before you will get positive responses, you will need to make a stab at it yourself.  Do some research and give it a try- if you have a problem with your code, come back to StackOverflow and ask.